# rails 3 array display value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi
How do i display the value of domain from this array:
{:domain=>"www.domain1.com"}, {:domain=>"domain1.com"}, {:domain=>"www.domain2.com"}

I have tried this:

```
<% @domains.each do |d| %>
    <%= d %><br />
<% end %>
```

That displays this:

domainwww.shopcms.dk

domaindomain1.com

domainwww.domain2.com

I have also tried to get valeu of domain like this
    <%= d.domain %>
That gives me an error.

Obviously I want to only display the Domain like www.domain1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @domains.each do |d| %>
  <%= d[:domain] %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

since each element is a hash, if you are sure it only contains one key, you can use

```
d[:domain]
```

to get the value and print it.

Comment: Thank you. What will happen i theres more than one value? And what can I do to make sure it always only display the hash value of :domain?